# Is it possible to pull from multiple Mercurial repositories at the same time?

Tags: mercurial

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
hg pull http://server/repo1 http://server/repo2 http://otherserver/repo
```

and have all of the changesets come down at once, with the "added x changesets with y changes to z files" message aggregating the results of all of the pulls. I'm currently doing this with a (marginally complex) bash script, but is there a way to do it with a single mercurial command (or an already-existing plugin) that I've missed?

Comment: You could create a "dummy" repo which only purpose is to contain the other repos as [sub repositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository).

Comment: Or rather, a "dummy" repo that pulls from all of the other repos, and which you then pull from with your main repo.

Answer (score 1):

As @James noted, **if** your repository have

PATH1 - REPO1

PATH2 - REPO2

...

structure, you can use "super-repo" idea and pull all included repos at once (but instead of subrepo extension I'll suggest [GuestRepo](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/GuestrepoExtension))

In case of common base in you repo for pull sources and combined changeset is **a must**, *you* **must** to use intermediate repository as collector. I.e

- Create intermediate repository

> hg clone WORK MEDIATOR

- Pull externals (from MEDIATOR)

> hg pull EXTERNAL1 & hg pull EXTERNAL2 ... hg pull EXTERNALN

- Pull mediator (from WORK)

> hg pull MEDIATOR