# In hg how do I pull all remotes/paths in one command?

Tags: mercurial, dvcs

I'm looking for the equivalent of `git fetch --all`. I currently have three different remote paths configured for my repository. `hg paths` shows all three. How do I do `hg pull --all` to fetch the new change sets from all remote repositories?

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12808759/1256452 - there's no concrete answer there though, just several ways of faking it.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I hadn't seen that. This question is a bit different in that the remotes are defined in the hgrc instead of on the command line. But I expect a solution for one will work for the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this with an alias. In your `~/.hgrc` add:

```
[alias]
pullall = !$HG paths | cut -f 1 -d ' ' | xargs -n 1 $HG pull
```

Then you can run `hg pullall` to fetch all the remotes.